# How to get all addresses and their transactions from XPUB with blockchain.com API?

Tags: blockchain.info

I know this question surface couple of times in different forms but people mostly were interested in doing that locally while I'm just starting with the topic and would like to know how to do that with blockchain.com API.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -1):

1. get data from here [https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/assets/btc/xpub/{xpub_key}](https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/assets/btc/xpub/%7Bxpub_key%7D)
2. scrap the results :)